# GET or POST value from controller to model in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Is there any way to pass value from one controller to model as GET or POST

I have 1 controller **V1** and 1 model **Vmodel**

```
class V1 extends CI_Controller {        
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Vmodel','',TRUE);
    }
    /* index action */
    public function index()
    {
      $user='abcd';
      $details  = $this->Vmodel->login();
    }       
}
```

model

```
class V1Modelnew extends CI_Model{
public function __construct() {

    }

          public function login()
          {
            //here, I need to get the user variable as post
            echo $_POST['user'];
          }
}
```

I need to get the value 'abcd' as POST in model. Any method to do this?

Comment: `$_POST['user'] ='abcd';` use this in controller

Answer (score 2):

Errors in your code

1. You load model as `$this->load->model('Vmodel'` But you define it has `V1Modelnew`
2. You are not passing `$user` value to your model function
3. There is no value associated with `$_POST['user']`

---

**In controller**

```
class V1 extends CI_Controller {        
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('V1Modelnew'); # Changed
    }

    public function index()
    {
      $user='abcd';
      $details  = $this->V1Modelnew->login($user); # Changed
    }       
}
```

**In Model**

```
class V1Modelnew extends CI_Model{

    public function __construct() 
    {

    }

    public function login($user) # Changed
    {
        echo $user; # Changed
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohh great I didn't see the model name... Good catch

Answer (score 0):

There is an architectural problem here. You don't want your model accessing values in the $_POST or $_GET. This couples your model layer to the HTTP layer of your application.

Instead, you want to pass the necessary values into your model as function arguments.

Your controller:

```
$details = $this->Vmodel->login('abcd', $_POST['password']);
```

And your model:

```
public function login($username, $password) {
    // return $details
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way

```
class V1 extends CI_Controller {        
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Vmodel','',TRUE);
    }
    /* index action */
    public function index()
    {
      $user=$this->input->post('user');
      $details  = $this->Vmodel->login($user);
    }       
}
```

Model:

```
class Vmodel extends CI_Model{ //use Vmodel NOT V1Modelnew 
public function __construct() {

    }

          public function login($user)
          {

            echo $user;
          }
}
```

If you want to user `post` and `get` you need to do it in Controller in this way:

```
$value = $this->input->post('value_name'); // for Post
$value = $this->input->get('value_name'); // for GET
```

For more, read [documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html)

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
class V1 extends CI_Controller {        
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Vmodel','',TRUE);
    }
    /* index action */
    public function index()
    {
      $user='abcd';
      $details  = $this->Vmodel->login($_POST);
    }       
}
```

Model

```
class V1Modelnew extends CI_Model{
public function __construct() {

    }

          public function login($data='')
          {
            //here, I need to get the user variable as post
            echo $_POST['user'];
          }
}
```